# Bash check if file1 line is partly contained in a line from file2

Tags: bash, file, iteration, contains

I have have a file1 with ids and a file2 that is a list with full names of all files in a folder.

Ids from file1 look like this P001A, P001I, P002A, P002I ...
And the names of the files from file2 contain those ids in themselves. I want to create a new file3 that contains all full names from file2 that have the ids from file1.

File2 has like 100k lines, while file1 has 89 so there are many lines from file2 that contain the same id from a line in file1.

This is the script that I am using, but it says

> FILE1: command not found FILE2: command not found
> -bash: ${FILE1}: ambiguous redirect

```
  1#!/bin/sh
  2 FILE1 ="$1"
  3 FILE2 ="$2"
  4 while read -r value1
  5 do
  6     while read -r value2
  7     do
  8         if [[ "$value1" == *"$value2"* ]]
  9             then
 10             echo $value2
 11         fi
 12     done <${FILE2}
 13 done <${FILE1} > file3.list
```

What is wrong here? And do you know if that script is supposed to be like that or I should make some other way.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/, it'll tell you about a lot of common mistakes. Off the bat: you use `/bin/sh`, but then you use `[[ ... ]]`, a Bashism; either switch to `case` for pattern matching, or use `/bin/bash` (or `/usr/bin/env bash`). Then, your assignments to `FILE1` and `FILE2` must not contain blanks around `=`.  Lastly, this is going to be extremely slow, you can do the same with `grep -Ff "$FILE2" -- "$FILE1"`.

Comment: Can you add some examples of extracts from the two files as well as the expected output.

Comment: @BenjaminW. What makes the -Ff option?  @ Raman Sailopal file2 has for example files from P001A0001 to P001A0120, while in file1 there is only P001A, and I want to store all files that contain the P001A id in a third file.

Comment: @PetarYakov: Please add sample data from both file in question

Comment: [`-F`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dF), [`-f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this script

```
  1#!/bin/bash
  2 for i in $(cat file1);
  3 do
  4    FILENAME=$(find /directory/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/20170001${i}[0-9]*\.wav")
  5    echo "${FILENAME}";
  6 done > file3
```

I didn't even need the file with the file names.

Answer (score 0):

as @Benjamin said - you use /bin/sh but use "[[" and "]]" to test.
I rewrote your code to use /bin/sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
is_substring(){
    case "$2" in
        *$1*) return 0;;
        *) return 1;;
    esac
}

FILE1="$1"
FILE2="$2"
while read -r value1
do
    while read -r value2
    do
        if is_substring "$value1" "$value2"
            then
            echo $value2
        fi
    done <${FILE2}
done <${FILE1} > file3.list
```

for bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1="$1"
FILE2="$2"
(while read -r value1
do
    (while read -r value2
    do
        if [[ -z "${value2##*$value1*}" ]]
            then
            echo $value2
        fi
done) < ${FILE2}
done <${FILE1}) > file3.list
```

Comment: Oh, it's my mistake I should use /bin/bash. What would be the syntax then?